# How to render visually a big pandas dataframe (~7000 lines, 3 columns)?

Tags: python, visualization, data-visualization, aspect-ratio, imshow

I have a big dataframe with values between -1 and 1. The dataframe has almost 7000 lines and 3 columns. I would like to have a visualization without the cells shrinking. For now, it's more lines than cells. I would like the color to refer to the value. I was trying with `imshow` but I don't find how to increase the height of cells. I've tried to play with extent and aspect but when aspect is increased, the picture shrinks.

Comment: You want to see all 21,000 "values" on screen at once? Let's have some fun. A typical screen rez may be 1280x1024. That's ~62 square pixels *per value* -- not counting the digits. About 8x8 pixels.

Comment: I was thinking about a kind of Heat Map. But It's not pretty for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most compact representation would be to use a bitmap of one pixel per value. This can be accomplished using PIL or [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/), by creating the image from a buffer of data.

```
import StringIO
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(buffer))
```

You would have to scale the data in the buffer to one or more bytes per pixel depending on the [mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/handbook/concepts.html#modes) of the image you want to create